# Search by Index dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column `Search` that contains string of the header as per:

```
Alpha Bravo Charlie Search SearchReturn
1      2      3     Alpha      1  
2      5      6     Charlie    6
```

I am trying to use something like excel Vlookup function for `SearchReturn` Column.

However, I have no idea how to create the `SearchReturn` Column, can you advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with row and column labels:

```
df['SearchReturn'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Search'])

print(df)

   Alpha  Bravo  Charlie   Search  SearchReturn
0      1      2        3    Alpha             1
1      2      5        6  Charlie             6
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
df['SearchReturn'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['Search']], axis=1)
```